# Splitting up a single polygon into many polygons of equal point count

Tags: polygon, point, polygon-creation

I have point data split into 15 different values and want to split up the (green) polygon into a number of smaller polygons each containing the same number of points so that I can make a chloropleth map showing which sort of value is dominant in each area. I'd also like to maintain the structure of the islands whilst I'm doing that. Was thinking something along the lines of finding the nearest x neighbors of each point and then clustering from that and then editing with the Cut Polygons Tool but was wondering if there were any tools / script that did it more efficiently?

[image: Current Project]

Comment: If you have ArcGIS you might look at the aggregate points tool.